# Is it possible to truncate a number just with Arithmetic operations?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Hi is it possible to truncate a number just with Arithmetic operations?

For example if i have

```
2.5
```

i want to get "2" without using modulo or something other which can't be rewritten in formulas.

i could calculate

```
2.5 * 0.8 = 2
```

but this just works for "2"

what i want to do:

```
2^x-trunc(2^x/13)*13=9
```

and now solve to x... i think there are many solutions

one solutuon is x=8

Comment: $a\lfloor y/a\rfloor$ is the largest multiple of $a$ no greater than $y$. So $y-a\lfloor y/a\rfloor$ is just $y\bmod a$. Therefore, your last equation is equivalent to $2^x\bmod13=9$.

Comment: yes i just tried to solve it to x... and modulo cant't be rewritten

Comment: @wuyzebaer: you don't rewrite the modulo: you solve it using mod-13 arithmetic (rather than, say, real arithmetic or complex aritmetic). Hopefully someone will write about discrete logarithms shortly; I'm not up to it ATM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are all continuous functions, and any combination of them will also be continuous. However, the floor and ceiling functions are not continuous.

---

Okay, after your edit, it seems you're trying to solve $2^x \equiv 9 \pmod{13}$. Don't rewrite this! It becomes harder to do with floor functions and all. Let's look at the powers of two.

$$\begin{array}{c||c}
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & \cdots \\
\hline
2^x & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 11 & 9 & 5 & 10 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & \cdots
\end{array}$$

First, we note that this table repeats after $12$. How can we be sure? Because, as we can see from the table, $2^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. (See if you can generalize this). The only solution for $x$ between $1$ and $12$ is $8$. So, our solution set is $x = 8 + 12k, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: and are there other operations like modulo which could help me?

Comment: Depends. How are you defining modulo for real numbers? If you have "a % b", can both a and b be non-integers?

Comment: for my particular problem both are integers

Comment: Are you rounding arbitrary decimals, or fractions with a certain size of denominator? Say you're only dealing with fractions with denominator 1000. Then your number is of the form $(1000x + y)/1000$, for some $y$ between $0$ and $999$. So you can multiply by 1000, then mod by 1000, giving you $y$. Then subtract $y/1000$ from your original number to get the floor. But really, you're much better off using a built-in floor function. (is this for a computer program?)

Comment: the floor function isn't my target, i want to be able to rip it into peaces and rewrite my formular

Comment: i've added my formular

Comment: @wutzebaer I've edited my original post to address it.

Comment: thanks i'll have a closer look at it on finishing time

Comment: and how can i calculate "8"? this is just trial and error... i wanted to solve the function to x

Comment: I made the table by multiplying by $2$ a bunch of times, until it started repeating. Look at the bottom row, where do you see a $9$? It's from the $8$ column, so we know $2^8 \equiv 9 \pmod{13}$. And since $2^{12}$ is one (again, see the table), we know $9 \equiv 2^8 \cdot 1 \equiv 2^8 \cdot 2^{12} \equiv 2^{20}$, so $20$ is also a solution. By the same logic, $8$ plus any number of $12$s is a solution.

Comment: and the part where you mulitply 2 until you find the first solution is trial and error, for bigger numbers it will take a lot of time, if 13 was a 200 digit number or better prime

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I could break several kinds of encryption :P There are ways to do it faster, but nothing fundamentally different, as far as I know.

Comment: so if i would find a continous trunc-function i could break an encryption?

Comment: Truncation is not a good way of computing mods. (Also, it's not a continuous function). If you could compute a [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) quickly, that would break a certain type of encryption. We can compute mods quickly (just division with remainder), but the problem is that we have so many options to try. I know $2^x \equiv 9 \pmod{13}$, but is $a^b = 9, 9 + 13, 9 + 2\cdot 13, \ldots$. Which was it? Only one is a power of two, and figuring out which one it is is hard without going through all of them.

Comment: hm, what about solving `2^x = x*13+9`?